# A ClassNotFundExxseption error occurs when the registration and initialization command is executed

Tags: java, postgresql, netbeans, jdbc-postgres

I have java project JavaProject4. In folder lib, I added file postgresql-42.2.2.jre7.jar (postgres driver). Next, I execute the following command:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance();
```

The command terminates with an error:

> type: ClassNotFoundException  detailMessage: "org.postgresql.Driver"

**Question:** how do I fix this error?

**P.S.** I'm a little versed in Java and the development environment of Netbeans.
[image]

Comment: i guess you have a dependency issue. You should check your dependencies.

Comment: The project is created successfully. There are only such warnings:
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint: unchecked for details.

Comment: You do not have the Postgres JDBC driver in your classpath. Just by copying it into a "lib" directory does not necessarily add it to the classpath of your project. Did you add it to the project's libraries in the NetBeans project properties?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `Class.forName()` has not been necessary any more for a long time

Comment: Yes, I added the postgresql-42.2.2.jre7.zar library to the project properties (see screenshot).

Comment: I executed the commands according to the [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/). The results of the commands: ..../lib/postgresql-42.2.2.jre7.jar ....

Comment: Download from this [link](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html)  postgresql-42.2.2.jre7.jar and added to the library and it all worked.